# am having an Error during installing react Native project

Tags: npm, url

npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_URL
npm ERR! Invalid URL

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\ACER\AppData\Local\npm-cache_lo
gs\2023-11-26T10_57_38_720Z-debug-0.log

i try running npm install to fix the previous problem during the installation

Comment: Can you please share the content of the log file?